# Calling new Thread with parameters in for-loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop

I'm testing a piece of code where a the same Task should be executed in a for loop, with variables updated every cycle.

```
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                _waitNextBatch++;
                Console.WriteLine($"{_waitNextBatch}");

                BatchSensor bs = new BatchSensor { SensorName = $"batch - {j}" };

                new Thread(() => SimulateBS(bs, j)).Start();
            }
```

In the method called by the Task I get the correct `bs`, but the `j` is the last iteration value for all the runs.

I just print the values received from the `SimulateBS` method

```
Console.WriteLine($"{bs.SensorName} | {j}");
```

And I get as output:

```
batch - 0 | 6
batch - 2 | 6
batch - 5 | 6
batch - 4 | 6
batch - 3 | 6
batch - 1 | 6
```

or

```
batch - 0 | 2
batch - 1 | 3
batch - 2 | 3
batch - 3 | 5
batch - 4 | 5
batch - 5 | 6
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this instead

```
var i = j;
new Thread(() => SimulateBS(bs, i)).Start();
```

Ultimately `j` is a captured *variable*; it is the *variable itself*, not the *current value of the variable*, that is captured - so currently all the delegates are sharing the same *variable*. By declaring `i` at a scope *inside the loop*, each loop iteration gets a different variable (via compiler voodoo).

Comment: (added some words to explain *why* this should help; hope that's OK)

Comment: Thanks @Marc Gravell for the complete answer !

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell for the answer and explanation. Is this valid also for `foreach` loop in list of objects?

Comment: @Oiproks it *was* at one point in C#'s history; however, it caught out so many people that they changed it - specifically the L-Value (i.e. `x` in `foreach (var x in something)` is now considered to be declared *inside* the loop for the purposes of captured variable analysis - and it no longer hurts folks